# Django: Redirect to correctly-cased URL

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I have a Django app, and I have a line like the following in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^piece/(?P<pk>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$', 'piece', name="piece-detail"),
```

I would like to match the `pk` ID case insensitively—that is, it shouldn't matter whether the user types in `A123` or `a123`.

One solution I thought of would be to catch the 404 exception in the view, converting the `pk` to uppercase as necessary and trying again. However, I wasn't sure this was a good idea; for one thing, it leaves open the possibility for multiple canonic URLs.

Is there a way to redirect a URL matching `(?P<pk>[0-9a-z]+)` to one with equivalent uppercase characters?

Comment: That part of your regex does match case-insensitive, but you could try using `(?P<pk>[^\W_]+)`

Comment: One won't you covert the case at the top of the view?

Comment: @hwnd If I understood well I think he wants to match case insensitively the capturing group name

Comment: It's not clear because `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` matches both..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (easiest) way to do it is the one you've described. Add a check in the beginning of your `piece` view to redirect the user if `pk` isn't uppercase:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def piece(request, pk):

    if pk != pk.upper():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/piece/{0}/".format(pk.upper()))

    # Normal code here.
    (...)
```